# transpose repeating range of matrix using Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have a situation where I have multiple groups of matrix that I would like to transpose and 
would like some help with Excel vba code. Thank you in advance for your help.

My table is as follows-(it will be 13 month view but I'm showing only 3 for this sample)

```
Group   month   color   shape   cost
A       Jan      B        S         1
A       Feb      G        T         2
A       Mar      Y        R         3
B       Jan      W        C         5
B       Feb      M        S         4
B       Mar      P        R         7
```

and so on (more groups and more months)
Desired result---

```
Group       Jan Feb Mar
A   color   B   G   Y   
    shape   S   T   R
    cost    1   2   3
B   color   W   M   P
    shape   C   S   R
    cost    5   4   7
```

and so on (with their values transposed)

sample code not exactly giving the above result but something I have used to start with.

```
Sub transposedata()
Dim vcol1 As Variant, vcol2 As Variant, vcol3 As Variant, vcol4 As Variant, vcol5 As Variant, vcol6 As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set ws = Sheets(1)

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

lastrow = lastrow - 1

vcol1 = WorksheetFunction.transpose(ws.Range("B2").Resize(lastrow).Value)
vcol2 = WorksheetFunction.transpose(ws.Range("C2").Resize(lastrow).Value)
vcol3 = WorksheetFunction.transpose(ws.Range("D2").Resize(lastrow).Value)
vcol4 = WorksheetFunction.transpose(ws.Range("E2").Resize(lastrow).Value)
vcol5 = WorksheetFunction.transpose(ws.Range("F2").Resize(lastrow).Value)
vcol6 = WorksheetFunction.transpose(ws.Range("G2").Resize(lastrow).Value)

ws.Range("J2").Resize(1, UBound(vcol1)) = vcol1
ws.Range("J3").Resize(1, UBound(vcol1)) = vcol2
ws.Range("J4").Resize(1, UBound(vcol1)) = vcol3
ws.Range("J5").Resize(1, UBound(vcol1)) = vcol4
ws.Range("J6").Resize(1, UBound(vcol1)) = vcol5
ws.Range("J7").Resize(1, UBound(vcol1)) = vcol6

End Sub
```

Comment: Where does that "T" in the result come from ?

Comment: Hello Tim, T is missing in the original data, there should be T under Shape column for Feb. Hope that helps. Please let me know if you have any additional questions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any code to share (even if it's not working)? Always helps to demonstrate you've tried *something*.

Comment: Hello Tim, here is the code I'm using-- it kind of works but I'm looking for first column and not looping so it creates not the same result as I expect. I need to loop and check value in the first column. Thanks again for your help. Here is the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested:

```
Sub Pivot()
    Const NUM_MONTHS As Long = 3
    Const NUM_PROPS As Long = 3

    Dim rng As Range, rngDest As Range, arrProps, x

    'first block of source data
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Resize(NUM_MONTHS, 5)

    'header labels
    arrProps = Application.Transpose(rng.Rows(1).Offset(-1, 0). _
                              Cells(3).Resize(1, NUM_PROPS).Value)

    'top-left of destination table
    Set rngDest = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J1")

    'set up headers
    With rngDest
        .Value = "Group"
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = "property"
        .Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, NUM_MONTHS).Value = _
                Application.Transpose(rng.Columns(2).Value)
    End With
    Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0)

    'copy data
    Do While rng.Cells(1).Value <> ""
        rngDest.Value = rng.Cells(1, 1).Value 'group
        'property names
        rngDest.Offset(0, 1).Resize(NUM_PROPS, 1).Value = arrProps

        'property values
        For x = 1 To NUM_PROPS
            rngDest.Offset(x - 1, 2).Resize(1, NUM_MONTHS).Value = _
                Application.Transpose(rng.Columns(2 + x).Value)
        Next x

        'move to next block
        Set rng = rng.Offset(NUM_MONTHS, 0)
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(3, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Group property Month Jan Feb
Group  Color B G
  Shape S  T
  Cost 1 2
A  Y W M
  R C S 
  3 5 4
B  P  
  R  
  7  
Hi Tim, Thank you for your help. I ran the code, it transposed Jan and Feb month data for both groups A and B. I'm not sure why March data moves to the next block. I'm not sure if I missed something. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Tim, I know what I missed, I moved data to start on row 1 A1. Thank you very much for your help. The code works great. I appreciate your help.